# unable to obtain desired line graph through datafram.plot()

Tags: pandas, data-visualization

```
years = list(map(str,range(1980,2014)))
df_can.loc[['Haiti'],years].plot(kind='line')
plt.title('Immigration from Haiti')
plt.ylabel('Number of immigrants')
plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.show()
```

This is the plot I'm getting from above code 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqM5F.png instead of line graph. I tried all different methods still not able to get the desired line graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To plot a line graph we  need two columns of data but the above code as two rows one with immigrants data and the other with year from 1980-2013. So, we transpose this to get two columns and as the years are column names in string we convert them to integer data type.

```
years = list(map(str,range(1980,2014))
df_canada=df_can.loc[['Haiti'],years].plot(kind='line').transpose()
df_canada.index= df_canada.index.map(int)
plt.title('Immigration from Haiti')
plt.ylabel('Number of immigrants')
plt.xlabel('Years') plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your data, so I can't recreate the graph, but I'm pretty sure you're just missing a for loop.

```
years = list(map(str,range(1980,2014)))
for i in years:
    df_can.loc[['Haiti'],i].plot(kind='line')
plt.title('Immigration from Haiti')
plt.ylabel('Number of immigrants')
plt.xlabel('Years')
plt.show()
```

Right now as your code stands you're trying to plot all of the years, and all of the data, on one line. It doesn't intuitively know to break it up.